# macos apps not going back to macbook display from external display when external display is powered off

Tags: macos

I have an external display connected to my macbook. External display doesn't have power backup. Whenever power goes off apps running on external display do not come back to the MacBook display. I have to remove the display cable to get them back. Anyone else facing this? Is this the default behaviour? Can it be fixed somehow or is there some workaround for it to get apps to macbook everytime external display is switched off or power goes off?

Comment: I don't have an answer but can confirm this happens to me on macOS 12.4. I run a 13" MBP with an external monitor. I believe that there is still a signal going from the monitor to the MBP even if the monitor is OFF. Only when the physical connection is severed does the MBP no longer "see" the monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works as intended. I have a display connected to a switch, so I can use it on the MacBook and another computer concurrently. If that would result in my apps being re-arranged or put the MacBook to sleep every time, it would be extremely annoying.